# How to know in which device an USB printer is mapped?

Tags: usb-device, printer

For example when I plug an USB printer (say, Canon), Debian use `/dev/usb/lp0`.
If I plug a second printer (say, HP), it is mapped to `/dev/usb/lp1`.
If I plug them in reverse order, then Canon=lp1 and HP=lp0.

So how a script can know which is which?

`lsusb -vvv` give no clue.
Neither `usb-devices` but maybe I miss something.